# Text count and substring in editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a message editor with editable div instead of textarea. I am struggling with character count in editable div. How I can get exact character count ?

1. If I use $("#eidtor").text(), then it does not count new lines while typing
2. If I user $("#eidtor").html(), then it gives me count with html contents while typing.
3. How I can handle If user paste text which is longer then maximum length. It creates `<div>...</div>` for new line in pasted text.
   If I do substring based on text then its new line character is getting removed.

I not looking for cross browser support solution. It should be working in google chrome. Any help, suggestion or guide will be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>     
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var maxLen = 200;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#eidtor").on("keydown", function (e) {handleKeydown(e);});

            $("#eidtor").on("keyup", function (e) { handleKeyup(e); });

            $("#eidtor").on("paste", function (e) { handlePaste(e); });

            $("#charCount").html(maxLen);
        });

        function handleKeydown(e) {
            var currentLen = $("#eidtor").text().length;            
            var keycode = e.keyCode;

            var valid =
                (keycode > 47 && keycode < 58) || // number keys
                keycode == 32 || keycode == 13 || // spacebar & return key(s) 
                (keycode > 64 && keycode < 91) || // letter keys
                (keycode > 95 && keycode < 112) || // numpad keys
                (keycode > 185 && keycode < 193) || // ;=,-./` (in order)
                (keycode > 218 && keycode < 223);   // [\]' (in order)

            if (valid && !e.ctrlKey) {
                currentLen++;
                if (currentLen > maxLen) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }

        function handleKeyup(e) {
            var currentLen = $("#eidtor").text().length;
            $("#charCount").html(maxLen-currentLen);
        }

        function handlePaste(e) {
            setTimeout(function (e) {
                var currentLen = $("#eidtor").text().length;
                if (currentLen > maxLen) {
                    var tempMessage = $("#eidtor").text().substring(0, maxLen);
                    $("#eidtor").empty();
                    $('#eidtor').html(tempMessage);
                    currentLen = maxLen;
                }
                $("#charCount").html(currentLen);
            });
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" >
        #eidtor {
            background-color: #fff;
            resize: none;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 10em;
            width: 20em;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            display:inline-block;
        }
       </style>
</head>
<body>   
<div id="container" style="margin-left:2em;">
    <div id="eidtor" style=""
     contenteditable="true"></div>
 <br/>
    Remaining Character(s) : <span id ="charCount"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know much about jQuery, but you can get the number of characters including linebreaks using `$0.innerText.length` in plain JavaScript in Chrome. Please note that Chrome appends an extra <br> at the end of editable divs, so you might need to subtract 1 from the value.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to check the html on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and found that it uses the `<pre>` tag, and then [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) says `Whitespace inside this element is displayed as typed.` Since the statement doesn't say about line breaks(though the example on mdn includes line breaks which behaves just like spaces), I tested in console on the editing-help page with `document.getElementById('foo').innerText.substr(7,1)==='\n'`, it yields `true`(when I can see the 7th char is a line break). Didn't know about this tag till today myself. Cheers!

Comment: If you paste a text with line breaks and check then you will get divs

Comment: @Arshad Sorry, not quite getting you here. Would you explain a bit more?